# Remove all rows that contain value VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on this for longer than I'd like to admit.  I'm comparing two Worksheets (A & B).  I'm looping through A-Column("B") and for each value in that column I'm checking it against B-Column("C").  If there's a match, I want to delete the entire row.

I've done it a number of different ways and I just can't get it to work. This is the original:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Purge()

Dim wipWS           As Worksheet
Dim invWS           As Worksheet
Dim C               As Range
Dim SourceLastRow   As Long
Dim DestLastRow     As Long
Dim LRow            As Long
Dim D               As Range

Set wipWS = Worksheets("Work in Process")
Set invWS = Worksheets("Inventory Allocation")

With wipWS
' find last row in Work in Process Column B
SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

' find last row in Inventory Allocation Column C
DestLastRow = invWS.Cells(invWS.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' define the searched range in "Inventory Allocation" sheet
Set C = invWS.Range("B1:B" & DestLastRow)

Set D = wipWS.Range("E1:E" & SourceLastRow)


    ' allways loop backwards when deleting rows or columns
    ' choose 1 of the 2 For loops below, according to where you want to delete
' the matching records

' --- according to PO request delete the row in Column B Sheet A
'  and the row in Column C in "Inventory Allocation" worksheet
' I am looping until row 3 looking at the PO original code
For LRow = SourceLastRow To 1 Step -1

    ' found a match between Column B and Column C
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(LRow, "E"), C, 0)) Then
        .Cells(LRow, 2).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        invWS.Cells(Application.Match(.Cells(LRow, "E"), C, 0), 2).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
   Next LRow
 End With

 End Sub
```

It works, except it leaves 1 row left (that should be deleted). I think I know why it's happening, except I have no idea of how to do it. I've tried a For loop and it works, except I have to set a range (eg., "A1:A200") and I want it to only loop through based on the number of rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For starters, your first For Each is not looping through column B. Take a look at the answer by @cullan, that seems to be doing the column looping that you want.

Comment: basicaly you want to compare Column B in Sheet A with Column C in Sheet B, and you have a 2 loops. Question: are you values in Sheet A Column B unique ? if they are you can have only 1 `For` loop and use `Match` Function or `VLookup` , it will speed you code run a lot

Comment: @Twigs look at my answer below, using the `Match` function

Comment: @ShaiRado I tweaked the code to make it work, but it's only performing a 1:1 deletion. For instance, In Sheet A, I only have one product code, but in Sheet B, there will be multiple-component codes associated to that one product code. Is there a way for it to delete all rows that match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running 2 loops, you can run 1 `For` loop in yout Worksheets("Work in Process"), scanning Column B, and then just use the `Match` function to search for that value in the entire `C` range - which is Set to Worksheets("Inventory Allocation") at Column C (untill last row that has data).

Note: when deleting rows, allways use a backward loop (`For` loop counting backwards).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Purge()

Dim wipWS           As Worksheet
Dim invWS           As Worksheet
Dim C               As Range
Dim SourceLastRow   As Long
Dim DestLastRow     As Long
Dim LRow            As Long

Set wipWS = Worksheets("Work in Process")
Set invWS = Worksheets("Inventory Allocation")

With wipWS
    ' find last row in Sheet A Column B
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' find last row in Sheet B Column C
    DestLastRow = invWS.Cells(invWS.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ' define the searched range in "Inventory Allocation" sheet
    Set C = invWS.Range("C1:C" & DestLastRow)

    ' allways loop backwards when deleting rows or columns
    ' choose 1 of the 2 For loops below, according to where you want to delete
    ' the matching records

    ' --- according to PO request delete the row in Column B Sheet A 
    '  and the row in Column C in "Inventory Allocation" worksheet 
    ' I am looping until row 3 looking at the PO original code
    For LRow = SourceLastRow To 3 Step -1

        ' found a match between Column B and Column C
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(LRow, "B"), C, 0)) Then
            .Cells(LRow, 2).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            invWS.Cells(Application.Match(.Cells(LRow, "B"), C, 0), 3).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next LRow             
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: OP's question isn't actually the clearest one, but I'd say he/she wants to delete "matching" rows in _destination_ sheet (i.e. `invWS` aka "Inventory Allocation")

Comment: @user3598756 thanks :) included both options in my answer

Comment: ok. and in this latter case it you're deleting the _first_ "matching" row in _destination_ sheet only, and not _all_ matching ones as it might seem OP's request. But I'm actually suspending my answer till Twigs gives some feedback!

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. Very helpful. I'm trying to delete the rows from both Worksheet A & B - that is, if they match. I'm creating my own inventory system, so I put the items that need to be made in Worksheet B and Worksheet B pull up all of the materials needed to make that item. Once it's complete, this script is supposed to delete all of the rows that contain the materials needed to make the item and then delete the finished good itself in Worksheet A.

Comment: @Twigs try the code now , I've edited to delete the rows in both worksheets A & B. Let me know if it works for you as you intended

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you! It's Thanksgiving so I have a number of toddlers running around, but I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I'll try it first thing tomorrow and let you know. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two Worksheets (A & B). You want to loop through A-Column("B") and for each value in that column, check against B-Column("C").
So you can have a counter (ie. bRow) to keep track of which row you are looking at in worksheet B

```
Dim cell as Range
Dim bRow as Integer
bRow = 1
With Worksheets("A")
    For Each cell in Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        If (cell.Value = Worksheets("B").Range("C" & bRow).Value0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Worksheets("B").Range("C" & bRow).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp 
        Else
            bRow = bRow + 1
        End If            
    Next cell
End WIth
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out. It's not pretty and I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing this, but here it is.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub purWIP()

Dim wipWS As Worksheet
Dim invWS As Worksheet
Dim P As Range
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer


Set wipWS = Worksheets("Work in Process")
Set invWS = Worksheets("Inventory Allocation")



' Start by checking conditions of a certain row
For x = wipWS.UsedRange.Rows.count To 1 Step -1
    With wipWS
        ' For each cell in wipWS I'm going to check whether a certain condition exists
        For Each P In wipWS.Range(.Cells(6, 5), .Cells(wipWS.Rows.count, 5).End(xlUp))
            'If it does, then I'm going to check the Inventory Allocation Worksheet to see if there's a match
            If (IsDate(P.Offset(0, 7))) Then
                invWS.Activate
                ' I do a for loop here and add 1 to i (this was the part that fixed it)
                For i = invWS.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1 To 3 Step -1
                    If invWS.Cells(i, "B") = P.Offset(0, 0) Then
                        invWS.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                Next
                P.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
wipWS.Activate
```

End Sub